# LaTeX on OS X stoped working after update

Tags: macos, latex, macports

I have TeX Live installed on my MacBook Pro with OS X 10.9.2. I installed TeX Live through MacPorts. Not long ago, I did an update of out of date packages. I just tried to compile a Tex document, and I get the following error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib  
 Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/latex
 Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I have seen that this error comes up for other questioners in different contexts with different commands. None of the fixes suggested in those contexts worked for me (or sometimes didn't make sense in this context). Is there a simple fix?

Comment: I’ve always found [MacTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex/) to be so much less hassle than anything else for installing TeXLive (with the notable exception of imagemagick and ghostscript which are installed in /usr/local).

Answer (score 4):

Try 'sudo port rev-upgrade' (which searches for and tries to repair broken linkages like this) or ask the question on the MacPorts mailing list. https://lists.macosforge.org/mailman/listinfo/macports-users

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me: 
After the upgrade, in my /Applications/TeX/ directory I found a FixMacTeX2013.pkg. Running this fixed the pdflatex issue.